# How to enable http response buffering on HaProxy?

Tags: haproxy

I hope I understand it right: HAProxy is able (http-mode) to
buffer the output (response) from a backend server, so that the
server process is made free as soon as possible. A slow client
would therefore "only" consume ressources on the HAProxy.
How much data from the response can be buffered by HAProxy?
Is there a config variable? Is it tcp/ip buffering or
buffering in HAProxy userspace?